# How to program at client side to get Html Snapshot (or to capture all texts) of entire GWT page?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

To let you understand what I want, please read this:

Suppose you have a GWT page (`mydomain.com#!article`). That page contain many widgets and data downloaded from DB. The DB data & the widgets are mixed into each other, for example a label can hold Customer Name (customer name came from DB).

So, everything on that page is javascript, ie when you view source you can only see Javascript. However, if you open that GWT page in Chrome & save it as "`myGwtArticlePage.htm`" into your local PC, then reopen the "`myGwtArticlePage.htm`", you can see that all the text, widgets... in "`myGwtArticlePage.htm`" is exactly the same as the ones in "`mydomain.com#!article`".

Now, you right-click & view-source of "`myGwtArticlePage.htm`", you will see not just Javascript but all text, & Db data & widget still in there.

So, the "`myGwtArticlePage.htm`" is called the Html Snapshot of the "`mydomain.com#!article`".

Are you Clear?

Now I want program at client side to be able to capture all texts of "`myGwtArticlePage.htm`".

So, MyArticlePresenter.java (in Client package) should work like this:

```
private AsyncCallback<GetArticleResult> getArticleCallback=new AsyncCallback<GetArticleResult>(){
    @Override
public void onSuccess(GetArticleResult result) {
        String articleData=result.getArticleData;
        //... many other data from DB .....

        myLabel.setText(articleData);
        //... many other widgets that setText of the DB data ....

        // Now what I should do here to get Html Snapshot of "`mydomain.com#!article`" ??

    }
}
```

Note: people say that I can use HTMLUnit, but HtmlUnit work at server not at client package. Besides, HTMLUnit couldn't parse GWTP page properly. GWTP is GWT app buit under GWTP framework.

I hope someone can help me to ask this question.

Comment: Try with `RootPanel.getBodyElement().getInnerHTML()` or `RootPanel.getBodyElement().getInnerText()`. You can call it for particular Element.

Comment: but it can't read text in celltable right?

Comment: I don't know what do you want to achieve? All the client side code is in `JavaScript`.

Comment: i want to make my GWTP app crawlable since HTMLUnit does not work for GWTP.

Answer (score 0):

Client code, by definition, has to run on the client - in the case of GWT or any HTML/JS app, this means in a web browser.

HtmlUnit *is* a web browser, but is one that never renders to the screen. You can still ask it for the HTML contents of the current page. It is entirely written in Java, so it runs easily in any JVM, including a server. Also consider PhantomJS, a headless Chromium - you can script it to take screenshots, export html, etc. It is a native app, you'd need to get the right build for your server, and you'd need to do the wiring to call PhantomJS.

HtmlUnit should work perfectly with GWT, when properly configured. `GWTTestCase`s by default use HtmlUnit to run GWT tests in a browser without launching a 'real' browser instance. To do this of course, HtmlUnit must run in a normal JVM, like what your server would be running on.

That said, you can't call into client code directly, but instead you just launch the HTML/JS (compiled from GWT/Java) page in the HtmlUnit browser.

Another detail to consider - speed. Especially if you are interested in being indexed by a search engine, speed is important for two reasons. First, the search engine will be hitting these pages quickly, and you don't want your server to be killed when Google/Yahoo/Bing drives by and downloads all the URLs it can find. Second, among other things, the server may take the speed of a url being finished into account when ranking the page.

- Dev mode is slow because of calling back and forth between the JS in the browser (even HtmlUnit) and the real Java. Since you are compiling your app to JS anyway, there is no need to use dev mode on the server
- Pre-loading pages: Consider running htmlunit periodically and generating plain html pages that can then be served up right away when requested. If your data doesn't change often, this could work well for you, and would be fastest of all, if the page was already pre-rendered and cached.

Finally, if already using GWTP, look into their Crawler Service, which appears to be designed to filter our URLs with encoded fragments and translate to #! tokens, then pass that to your GWTP application. See https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Crawler-Support for more details.

Comment: A recent discussion on g+ about this: https://plus.google.com/115302996948824154724/posts/d6QKrxwD3XN

Comment: Hi, Thax you for your answer, HTMLUnit doesn't work for GWTP & Google Crawler Service just make the page blank & not very stable. Also, GWTP have a lot of String inside <span> <div>, ex <span title="Text">. My question is will google index the title property of <span>? Many people said Google crawler won't bore to index it since too much data in html page.... & Headless browser is unstable, you have to guess to set HTMLUnit timeout.... & It is slow, So i use the server side Snapshot solution. It's fast & focus thus it does not show 100% html Gui as HTMLUnit

Comment: but the the crawler won't need too much data right.

Comment: Do you thin Crawler Service work fine? check this link
http://crawlservice.appspot.com/?key=123456&url=http://chessbomb.com/site/ --> why it doesn't show all texts of http://chessbomb.com/site/ which has a very long list of texts in it.

Comment: I'm certain that GWTP itself is unit tested, undoubtedly with the help of HtmlUnit. I'm also not sure what crawlservice.appspot.com is supposed to do exactly, but it does seem to return the content that you get when viewing the source of http://chessbomb.com/site/?_escaped_fragment_=, as expected. That said, the returned html is the same that you get from chessbomb.com/site/, so the crawler service doesn't seem to be correctly generating the right html, if it is even enabled. Compare with http://www.arcbees.com vs http://www.arcbees.com/?_escaped_fragment_= with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: I am using Objectify 2.2.2 but it doesn't have  ObjectifyService.ofy();// why it is?

Comment: Hi Colin, I am using this example https://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/source/browse/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-crawler-service/?name=gwtp-0.6#gwtp-sample-crawler-service%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgwtplatform%2Fsamples%2Fcrawlerservice%2Fserver

Comment: I created 2 classes: CrawlerGuiceServletContextListener.java & CrawlerModule.java in my server package & added this line  <listener-class>com.gwtplatform.samples.crawlerservice.server.CrawlerGuiceServletContextListener
                </listener-class> into web.xml but it showed homepage. Do i need to compile my project?

Comment: after compiled & copy to Tomcat webapps & no when i go to any page I saw nothing completely blank. Ex: http://localhost:8080/ shows nothing, http://localhost:8080/ , localhost:8080/#!article --> why? but my app runs ok in eclipse? why?

Comment: when trying localhost:8080/?_escaped_fragment_=article it showed a blank page & TOmcat said "com.gwtplatform.crawler.server.CrawlFilter doFilter Info: Crawl filter exiting, no chaning" so crawlservice.appspot.com is not stable isn't it???

Comment: seem a person named Philippe Beaudoin built this CrawlerService but it's not very effective I think, so many problems

Comment: The crawler service produce a lightweight version of the site. Google is picking up everything correctly see this:
https://www.google.com/search?q=arcbees+service&oq=arcbees+service&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i64.6103j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=arcbees+consulting+development

and on bing:
http://www.bing.com/search?q=arcbees+consulting+development&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&filt=all&pq=arcbees+consulting+development&sc=0-8&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=237dd510467c498389ceec9c1b344fba

Comment: @Christian, can google & bing read the dynamic content of Arcbees? Do you have CrawlerGuiceServletContextListener.java & CrawlerModule.java in my server package of ArcBees?

Comment: also, "http://crawlservice.appspot.com/?key=123456&url=http://www.arcbees.com/#!service" does not have the text "Consulting". It mostly has javascript code. Or you mean even it show no text but Google still can read text via Javascript code?

Comment: We do use the Crawler for Arcbees website, although, we use the same external service for every single site web have. Bing can read dynamic content and isn't a problem